# Target DIV that sits above every image

Tags: jquery

got some HTML as below:

```
<div class="projectContentWrapperOverlayDIV"></div>
<img src="image1.jpg">

<div class="projectContentWrapperOverlayDIV"></div>
<img src="image2.jpg">

<div class="projectContentWrapperOverlayDIV"></div>
<img src="image3.jpg">
```

And I want to be able to set the width and height of each `<div class="projectContentWrapperOverlayDIV"></div>` to be the same as the JPEG it sits above in the markup - they are all different sizes and %s so change on resize of browser window.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you clarify the question please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method and set the current width and height of each pervious div to be the current image you are on using [`$(this).prev('.projectContentWrapperOverlayDIV')`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```
// For each image
$("img").each(function(){
    // Set the width/height of the previous div to be the current image width/height.
    $(this).prev('.projectContentWrapperOverlayDIV').width($(this).width());
    $(this).prev('.projectContentWrapperOverlayDIV').height($(this).height());
});
```

[**Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ghvbvjso/)